# I dont understand what liquibase diff is trying to determine with these selects?

Tags: informix, postgresql-9.2, liquibase

I dont understand why liquibase, when doing a diff, performs the selects where 0=1 shown below?

The comment says "checking for auto-increment with SQL", but I dont understand how the selects are supposed to work.  I tried the selects in both Informix and Postgress, and neither returned any rows.

---

Log from execution of liquibase diff:

DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Connected to khhis@jdbc:informix-sqli://stmst3.test.trnswrks.com:56670:informixserver=stmst3;database=edi

DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true
  DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Executing EXECUTE database command:   EXECUTE PROCEDURE IFX_ALLOW_NEWLINE('T');

DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Connected to khhis@jdbc:informix-sqli://stmsq3.qa.trnswrks.com:56070:informixserver=stmsq3;database=edi

DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true

DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Executing EXECUTE database command: EXECUTE PROCEDURE IFX_ALLOW_NEWLINE('T');

DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Computed checksum for 1421962892055 as b070ab11550d2082fedb3e665e9d1101

DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Checking edipro_function.edi for auto-increment with SQL: 'select edipro_function from informix.edipro_function where 0=1'

DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Checking edipro_function.edi for auto-increment with SQL: 'select function_type from informix.edipro_function where 0=1'

DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Checking edipro_function.edi for auto-increment with SQL: 'select company from informix.edipro_function where 0=1'

DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Checking edipro_function.edi for auto-increment with SQL: 'select edipro_send_recv from informix.edipro_function where 0=1'

DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Checking edipro_function.edi for auto-increment with SQL: 'select data from informix.edipro_function where 0=1'

DEBUG 1/22/15 4:41 PM: liquibase: Checking edipro_function.edi for auto-increment with SQL: 'select value from informix.edipro_function where 0=1'

Answer (score 0):

Typically select statements like this are used to get the header information for a query.